# How to add a progress bar in python?

Tags: python

I've been asked to make a 'Privilege Checker' and so far it is coming along pretty well. Here is my code:

```
def Privilige():
     print("Welcome to Privilege checker V0.011")
     print("Would you like to check your privileges?")
     answer = input("Type 'Yes' or 'No' and hit enter ('Y', 'y', 'N', or 'n' are also valid choices).")
     print("Checking priviliges.")
     if answer == "yes" or answer == "Yes" or answer == "Y" or answer == 'y':
         print("Privileges: Checked")
     elif answer == "no" or answer == "No" or answer == 'N' or answer == 'n':
         print("Privileges: Unchecked.")
     else:
          print("Please enter a valid option.")
Privilige()
```

Now, in between `print("Checking privileges.")` and `if answer == "yes"` I would like to add a progress bar that uses this character, "█" is this possible?
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Consider `answer.lower() in ('yes', 'y')` instead of multiple tests. Drop by codereview.stackexchange.com with the full script if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(60):  # Change this number to make it longer or shorter.
    print('█', end='')
    sleep(0.1)  # Change this number to make it faster or slower.
```